# Can I abort a Blitzball league?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I am two games into a Blitzball league with terrible prizes and just became eligible to have the Jupiter Sigil added to the league prize pool.  Since the only reason I'm playing Blitzball is to get Wakka's celestial weapon, I'm not really interested in playing a whole bunch of games while I wait for the [50% chance the sigil will show up](http://www.angelfire.com/hero/lalala/Blitzball-prizes.html).

I know if I am losing a league match, I can press triangle when I control the ball and forfeit the game, but that assumes the AI scores and sometimes they don't even try.

Is there a quicker method to burn through unwanted league games or repick league prizes?

I'm playing the FFX HD Remaster version on PS3.

Comment: I played Blitzball for fun!

Comment: I did too...at first.  But now I can literally walk away while the game plays itself and the enemy team doesn't score in either half.  It just gets repetitive after the first fifty games. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless this changed on the PS3 version, the answer is no.  In fact, as soon as you can view the league prizes, they become fixed until the league is over.  The same goes for tournaments.  You can save your game before viewing any rewards and then load it to "reroll" different awards.  That's about the extent of it.

Now there IS an option to reset all blitzball data.  That might work, but the price is pretty heavy!

Comment: That's what I feared.  At least the game mostly plays itself when I remove all tackle skills from my players.